# Get first unique entry - table with two uuid fields

Tags: postgresql

We want to get unique entries of a table with duplicates.

Simplified we have the following table setup:

```
id(uuid)    | title (character) | fingerprint (uuid)| created_at(timestamp)
123-0-1-321 | Dogs              | 123-0-1-321       | 2021-12-06 00:00:01
344-0-1-321 | Dog               | 123-0-1-321       | 2018-13-06 00:00:01
888-0-1-321 | Cats              | 888-0-1-321       | 2020-12-06 00:00:01
777-0-1-321 | Birds             | 999-0-1-321       | 2019-12-06 00:00:01
555-0-1-321 | Birds1            | 999-0-1-321       | 2022-12-06 00:00:01
```

We want to get distinct values by fingerprint. We currently do this by `DISTINCT ON` which is working fine:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (fingerprint) * 
FROM "tile" 
ORDER BY fingerprint, updated_at DESC;
```

But now we face a problem with searching by "title" (with an search vector). Problem is that we want to sort the results by search relevance. But because of the `DISTINCT ON fingerprint` we always have to use `fingerprint` as first `ORDER BY` parameter. So the search relevance as 2nd order-by parameter doesn't really work anymore.

I would prefer something like this, but it's not working:

```
SELECT FIRST(id), fingerprint 
FROM "tile" 
GROUP BY fingerprint 
ORDER BY search_relevance;
```

`MIN(id)` and `MAX(id)` is of course not working too, as `id` is an uuid-field.

Comment: `first_value() over (...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply cast `id` to `text`, then you can do all these things.